# Update set method for class type object

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following code and this code the casting is  hard-coded (Person) Since object is generic type there is a way to get it during run-time with reflection ?
**I don't have the classes type** and I get it just during Runtime (can be many different class)
but all the classes have the same method **setId**,how I can do it  ?

```
List<Object> listClsObj
    for (Object object : listClsObj) {
            ((Person)object).setId(null);
        }
```

I tried with (object.getClass().setId(null); and I got sytax error and also tried with

```
Class<?> clazz = object.getClass(); 
(clazz).setId(null);
```

and also get syntax error (maybe I didnt do it well ),how should I handle it assume that I dont know the class type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following code

```
Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
                Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("id");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(object, null);
```

Comment: It is better to set original visibility for the field after hack.

Comment: after setting accessible field it is better to return to previous state

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Object curObject : objectsList){
    try {
        Method method = curObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setId", Integer.class); //suppose only one parameter in method
        method.invoke(curObject, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //no such method exists
    }
}
```

---

of course it is better to use appropriate Object oriented design. For example if it is your entity it is better to use [Layer Supertype Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/layerSupertype.html) with basic implementation of *primary key* setting.